# Why are MariaDB versions different with same configurations?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So, last night I install a fresh copy of ubuntu 14.04 and followed some instructions for installing MariaDB as follows:

```
> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
> sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
> sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://sgp1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu trusty main'
> sudo apt-get update 
> sudo apt-get install mariadb-server mariadb-client
```

This worked great.   So, I figured that I'd go ahead and change another server (that I set up a few months ago) so that it would be exactly the same.   (It was already running MariaDB.)   So, I did the exact same steps -- thinking it would simply upgrade the other server.

But...it created a mess.   After quite a bit of hassle, I FINALLY got MariaDB re-installed on the other server...with liberal use of "dpkg --remove --force-depends ..."

Anyway, so now my question is this.   Why can't I seem to get both of these servers running the same version as stated on phpMyAdmin?   Right now the new server says this on the status page:

```
Server version: 5.5.41-MariaDB-1~trusty-log - mariadb.org binary distribution
Database client version: libmysql - 5.5.41-MariaDB
```

...while the old server says this:

```
Server version: 5.5.40-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
```

Everything seems to be working, but it nags at me.   The old server has all of the 5.5.41 packages installed (showing below) ...but phpMyAdmin still shows 5.5.40

```
> sudo dpkg --list | grep -i 'maria'
ii  libmariadbclient18                    5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                amd64        MariaDB database client library
ii  libmysqlclient18                      5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                amd64        Virtual package to satisfy external depends
ii  mariadb-client                        5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                all          MariaDB database client (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mariadb-client-5.5                    5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                amd64        MariaDB database client binaries
ii  mariadb-client-core-5.5               5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                amd64        MariaDB database core client binaries
ii  mariadb-common                        5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf)
ii  mariadb-server                        5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                all          MariaDB database server (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mariadb-server-5.5                    5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                amd64        MariaDB database server binaries
ii  mariadb-server-core-5.5               5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                amd64        MariaDB database core server files
ii  mysql-common                          5.5.41+maria-1~trusty                all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/my.cnf)
```

I feel like perhaps the problem is mysqld-server, etc. didn't really uninstall properly on the old server before I added MariaDB ...but, I swear I followed all of the instructions.

One final bit of information -- on the NEW server:

```
> sudo service mysql status
 * /usr/bin/mysqladmin  Ver 9.0 Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64
Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Server version          5.5.41-MariaDB-1~trusty-log
Protocol version        10
Connection              Localhost via UNIX socket
UNIX socket             /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 1 hour 2 min 55 sec

Threads: 1  Questions: 124  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 78  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 51  Queries per second avg: 0.032
```

On the old server:

```
> sudo service mysql status
mysql start/running, process 7346
```

Anyway, if anyone has any thoughts, I'd be curious to hear them.   Honestly, what I'd like to do is completely remove MariaDB/MySQL on the old server and start from scratch so that it matches exactly what I have on the new server.   But, any time I try to do this ....it just installs the same version as what it had ...it doesn't seem to want to match the new server, even though both are running Ubuntu 14.04